# Neo4j - complete a query with an alternative match if it finds few results

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am trying to write a query which looks for potential friends in a Neo4j db based on common friends and interests.

I don't want to post the whole query (part of school assignment), but this is the important part

```
MATCH (me:User {firstname: "Name"}), (me)-[:FRIEND]->(friend:User)<-[:FRIEND]-(potential:User), (me)-[:MEMBER]->(i:Interest)
WHERE NOT (potential)-[:FRIEND]->(me)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT potential) AS potentialFriends, 
     COLLECT(DISTINCT friend) AS friends, 
     COLLECT(i) as interests

UNWIND potentialFriends AS potential

/*
 @HANDLING_FINDINGS
 Here I count common friends, interests and try to find relationships between 
 potential friends too -- hence the collect/unwind 
*/

RETURN potential, 
       commonFriends, 
       commonInterests, 
       (commonFriends+commonInterests) as totalPotential 
ORDER BY totalPotential DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

In the section @HANDLING_FINDINGS I use the found potential friends to find relationships between each other and calculate their potential (i.e. sum of shared friends and common interests) and then order them by potential.

The problem is that there might be users with no friends whom I would also like to recommend someone friends.

**My question** - can I somehow insert a few random users into the "potential" findings if their count is below 10 so that everyone gets a recommendation?

I have tried something like this

```
...
UNWIND potentialFriends AS potential
CASE
WHEN (count(potential) < 10 ) 
...
```

But that produced an error as soon as it hit start of the CASE. I think that case can be used only as part of a command like return? (maybe just return)

**Edit with 2nd related question:**
I was already thinking of matching all users and then ranking them based on common friends/interestes, but wouldn't searching through the whole DB be intensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CASE` expression can be used wherever a value is needed, but it cannot be used as a complete clause.

With respect to your main question, you can put a `WITH` clause like the following between your existing `WITH` and `UNWIND` clauses:

```
WITH friends, interests,
  CASE WHEN SIZE(potentialFriends) < 10 THEN {randomFriends} ELSE potentialFriends END AS potentialFriends
```

If the size of the `potentialFriends` collection is less than 10, the `CASE` expression assigns the value of the `{randomFriends}` [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html) to `potentialFriends`.

As for your second question, yes it would be expensive.